# itunes persistent id - music library xml version and iTunes hex version

Tags: python, hex, itunes, itunes-sdk

I'd like to read a hex `PersistentID` string from `ItunesMusicLibrary.xml`, get two `ints` representing the high and low 32 bits, then use those two `ints` in an iTunes script.

Unfortunately, the `PersistentID` string in `ItunesMusicLibrary.xml` does not seem to be the same `PersistentID` that's in iTunes, as accessible through various scripting interfaces

iTunes music `library.xml` includes a 64 bit key, `PersistentID`.  For example,

```
<key>Persistent ID</key><string>0F1610959DA92DAB</string>.
```

You can also get the `PersistentID` through a script using the windows COM interface. For example,

```
iTunes.ITObjectPersistentIDHigh(track) -> 253104277

iTunes.ITObjectPersistentIDLow(track) -> -1649857109
```

If I feed those two numbers back into iTunes, I get the correct track

```
iTunes.LibraryPlaylist.Tracks.ItemByPersistentID(253104277,-1649857109).Name
```

My problem is translating the hex string from the xml library to high and low integers

For example, in python

```
int('0F1610959DA92DAB'[:8], 16) -> 253104277
int('0F1610959DA92DAB'[8:], 16) -> 2645110187
```

The first is correct, the second is not.  If I feed the two values back into iTunes, it doesn't work.  Using other tracks, sometimes both numbers are wrong.

Any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're interpreting the numbers as unsigned but iTunes is using signed.  2645110187 is the same as -1649857109.  You might want something like this:

```
struct.unpack('!i', binascii.a2b_hex('0F1610959DA92DAB'[8:]))[0]
```

...or get both values in one go:

```
struct.unpack('!ii', binascii.a2b_hex('0F1610959DA92DAB'))
```

...which gives you the tuple you need:

```
(253104277, -1649857109)
```

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: Perhaps because I'm in Python 3.2

Comment: The 3.2 version is: struct.unpack('!ii', bytes.fromhex(h))

Answer (score 0):

This works in 3.2, but there must be a simpler way

```
pID = '0F1610959DA92DAB'
b = bytes(pID, 'utf-8')
blo = b[8:]
b2a = binascii.a2b_hex(blo)
print(int.from_bytes(b2a, byteorder='big', signed=True))
bhi = b[:8]
b2a = binascii.a2b_hex(bhi)
print(int.from_bytes(b2a, byteorder='big', signed=True))
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727875/hex-string-to-signed-int-in-python-3-2/6727975