# Python: Convert hex string to int and back

Tags: python, string, hex, data-conversion

My python script gets and sends words over a serial line.
Each word is a **signed 24-bit value**, received as **hex string**.
The script should now take these strings and convert them to **integers**, do some calculations on it, and send them back in the same format.
My problem is, how to do this conversion

```
Examples

Rx string -> calc int
 012345   ->  74565
 fedcba   -> -74566

calc int -> Tx string
  74565  -> 012345
 -74566  -> fedcba
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Please confirm: the serial data is six bytes of `'0'`-padded text in the range `0-9a-fA-F`. It is not 3-bytes of binary data. Is that correct?

Comment: Can your **Task Definition** also explicitly confirm any form of a lower-level serial line-code protocol present ( data-bits, stop-bits, parity, CRC, framing, HDB3-transmission-line-code-protection et al)?

Comment: @user3666197: there is another part of the software which treats the low level stuff, my part only gets/sets the 6 char string

Comment: "*there is another part of the software which treats the low level stuff*" - that makes much more sense. It seemed unlikely that hardware guys would design a serial line protocol like you described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def str_to_int(s):
    i = int(s, 16)
    if i >= 2**23:
        i -= 2**24
    return i

def int_to_str(i):
    return '%06x'%((i+2**24)%2**24)
```

Test results:

```
In [36]: str_to_int('012345')
Out[36]: 74565

In [37]: str_to_int('fedcba')
Out[37]: -74566

In [38]: int_to_str(74565)
Out[38]: '012345'

In [39]: int_to_str(-74566)
Out[39]: 'fedcba'
```

Reference: [Hex string to signed int in Python 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727875/hex-string-to-signed-int-in-python-3-2)

Comment: Could you explain why you perform the subtractions? Is that simply to make use of the negative ints as well?

Answer (score 2):

(Edit: An oversight on my part. See [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26283443/923794) for correctly covering the negative sign numbers)

If you just want to convert a hex string into an int, do e.g.:

```
>>> int('0xff', 16)
255
>>> int('0xdaad', 16)
55981
```

The reverse can be done with the `hex()` function. From the help page:

Help on built-in function hex in module builtins:

```
>>> help(hex)
hex(...)
    hex(number) -> string

    Return the hexadecimal representation of an integer.

       >>> hex(3735928559)
       '0xdeadbeef'
```

It should be trivial to remove or add the '0x' if it's missing in your data stream.
Here's an example to ensure padding to 6 chars (representing 3 bytes = 24 bits):

```
>>> '0x' + hex(255)[2:].rjust(6, '0')
'0x0000ff'
```

If you get the data in 3 byte form (24 bits), you can use `int.to_bytes()` and `int.from_bytes()` as described in [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types). This is new in Python 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ pip install bitstring
```

Then:

```
from bitstring import BitStream
s1 = BitStream('0x012345')
s1.int # 74565
s2 = BitStream(int=-74565, length=24)
s2.hex # fedcbb
```

Comment: I marked the answer of @Robᵩ, because his solution does not need installing a module.