# Python convert int to unsigned short then back to int

Tags: python, type-conversion, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

A coordinate x,y is encoded in a integer using this function

```py
# Convert X Y position to MAP file index
def index_from_xy(x, y):
  return (y - 16) << 16 | (x & 65535)
```

It seems that x has been converted into an unsigned short.

x and y are within the range [-32767 32767]

What is the function that will convert the index into a x, y tuple ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All python integers are long under the hood (unless you're playing with bigger numbers).

To extract x and y, just reverse the steps of the above function.

```
def int_to_signed_short(value):
    return -(value & 0x8000) | (value & 0x7fff)

def xy_from_index(index):
    x, y = index & 65535, (index >> 16) + 16
    return map(int_to_signed_short, [x, y])
```

In more detail, your function takes the two numbers and shifts them in binary so they don't overlap with each other.

`x & 65535` only keeps the 16 rightmost bits of `x`, since 65535 is 16 1s in binary. Read more about [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

`(y - 16) << 16` shifts the number `y - 16` 16 bits to the left. So if your number was XXXXX in binary, it will become XXXXX0000000000000000. Read more about [bitwise shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift).

`A | B` will OR the bits of both numbers. Since A has 16 0s to the right and B is at most 16 bits long, A and B will not interfere with each other's bits. Read more about [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)

Once you understand that, it should become clear how my function is the inverse of this.

**Example**

```
>>> index = index_from_xy(1234, 5678)
>>> index
371066066
>>> xy_from_index(index)
(1234, 5678)
```

Comment: It does'nt work >>> xy_from_index(index_from_xy(-100, 70))
(65436, 70)

Comment: A "signed" integer is just a convention in which every value with most significat bit set to 1 is considered negative. If you want to treat those as signed, you should do the same. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727875/hex-string-to-signed-int-in-python-3-2

Comment: @nicolas-f Good catch, I hadn't considered negative numbers. See the updated answer.