# Python convert Hex string to Signed Integer

Tags: python

I have a hex string, for instance: 0xb69958096aff3148

And I want to convert this to a signed integer like: -5289099489896877752

In Python, if I use the int() function on above hex number, it returns me a positive value as shown below:

```
>>> int(0xb69958096aff3148)
13157644583812673864L
```

However, if I use the "Hex" to "Dec" feature on Windows Calculator, I get the value as: -5289099489896877752

And I need the above signed representation.

For 32-bit numbers, as I understand, we could do the following:

```
struct.unpack('>i', s)
```

How can I do it for 64-bit integers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a 64-bit version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727875/hex-string-to-signed-int-in-python-3-2), for example:

```
def signed_int(h):
    x = int(h, 16)
    if x > 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:
        x -= 0x10000000000000000
    return x


print(signed_int('0xb69958096aff3148'))
```

**Output**

```
-5289099489896877752
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert it to 64-bit signed integer then you can still use `struct` and pack it as unsigned integer (`'Q'`), then unpack as signed (`'q'`):

```
>>> struct.unpack('<q', struct.pack('<Q', int('0xb69958096aff3148', 16)))
(-5289099489896877752,)
```

Comment: Or `struct.unpack('>q', bytearray.fromhex('b69958096aff3148'))`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the `bitstring` package available through conda or pip.

```
from bitstring import BitArray
b = BitArray('0xb69958096aff3148')
b.int
# returns
-5289099489896877752
```

Want the unsigned int?:

```
b.uint
# returns:
13157644583812673864
```