# Python Hex to Signed Integer conversion

Tags: c, scanf

I am debugging a C program which accepts input through scanf() using %ld as the format.

I need to send an input such that it is equal to `0xfffffffffffffffa`.

If I convert the above hex value to decimal using Python, I get: 18446744073709551610 as shown below:

```
>>> a = 0xfffffffffffffffa
>>> a
18446744073709551610L
```

However, when I debug the program, I can see that the value was read by the program as: 0x7fffffffffffffff

So, is there a way to generate a decimal such that scanf() reads it as 0xfffffffffffffffa instead of 0x7fffffffffffffff?

Comment: Did you look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727875/hex-string-to-signed-int-in-python-3-2#6727975

Comment: `%ld` stores the result as a 64-bit *signed* integer (`signed long long`) and `0xfffffffffffffffa` overflows.

Comment: Must your C code accept a *signed* integer? Is -1 a valid input? If not, don't use `d`, use `l`: `%llu`, to switch the acceptable range to positive integers up to `0xffffffffffffffff`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `signed long`; and the conversion specifier is `u` for unsigned, and it must be matched with `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` argument

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: yeah, already corrected. C scanf manpage reading is not my strong point. :-P

Answer (score 0):

There are *2* conversion specifiers for `scanf` for reading decimal numbers. `u` reads an *unsigned decimal integer* - into a variable of *unsigned integer type*, and `d` reads a *signed decimal integer* (into a variable of signed integer type). When reading signed decimal integer, the maximum for a 64-bit 2's complement number would be `2 ** 63 - 1` i.e. `9223372036854775807`. When a number exceeding this is matched, `scanf` would still match it, but set the corresponding argument to the maximum value.

For unsigned 64-bit, the maximum would be `2 ** 64 - 1`. `18446744073709551610` would work for *unsigned input*, but you need the signed number for which `0xfffffffffffffffa` is the 2's complement representation. It is actually

```
>>> 0xfffffffffffffffa - 2 ** 64
-6
```

because the negative numbers are converted to unsigned by repeatedly adding or subtracting one larger than the maximum value until the value fits within the range - we now invert the operation and get `-6`.

---

Note that it is not correct to scanf into an object using `%ld` **and** then printf its value using `%lx` as you seem to do, unless the variable is a signed `int` and `printf` invocation has a cast to the argument to `unsigned` - because `%lx` requires an `unsigned long` int! If your compiler does not warn about it, then do add a switch such as `-Wall` to enable extra diagnostics.

Comment: It should be mantioned that the format specifier must exactly match the type of the destination variable; trying to read into `signed long long` with `%llu` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @M.M better?  Apparently it is `long int` they're using

Comment: better although it's already UB to scan with `%ld` if the object is declared as having unsigned type, even if you don't go on to print

Comment: @M.M the last addition there... blah can't bother to be `-pedantic-errors-extra-whiney`:D