# Converting hexstr to signed integer - Python

Tags: python, integer, signed

I have this hexstr `0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdf05d84162877`, in decimal terms it should give `-580140491462537`. However doing the below leads to bad answers. Can someone help?

```
In: test = '0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdf05d84162877'
In: int(test,16)
Out: 11579208923731619542357098500868790785326998466564056403945758342777263817739
```

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727875/hex-string-to-signed-int-in-python-3-2) help at all?

Comment: Yeah i tried `twos_complement` and the other suggestions, they all led to that long numbered answer... I think it's related to how negative integers are in hexstr form

Comment: It's important to note that the answer you're getting isn't wrong, it's just that the default representation that Python is using isn't the same as the one you're trying to use. If you're doing this for educational purposes, one of the things that this lesson is trying to teach is the difference between the representation of a value and the value itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert the string to bytes.  You'll have to remove the leading "0x".
Then use int.from_bytes and specify that it's signed and big-endian.

```
In: int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex(test[2:]), byteorder="big", signed=True)
Out: -580140491462537
```

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28489512)

```py
# hex string to signed integer
def htosi(val):
    uintval = int(val, 16)
    bits = 4 * len(val)
    indicative_binary = 2 ** (bits)
    indicative_binary_1 = 2 ** (bits-1)
    if uintval >= indicative_binary_1:
        uintval = int(0 - (indicative_binary - uintval))
    return uintval
```

This does require a pure hex string:

```
test1 = 'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdf05d84162877'
print(htosi(test1))

-580140491462537
```

Comment: thank you for your help, really appreciate it