# Interpret hex as signed integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I'm aware I could just do `0x0 - 9223372036854775807 - 1`, but is there a bit shift operation I could do instead to make this faster? Context: I'm fed a uint64 number in hex string form but I want to store this number inside an 8 byte signed integer attr in PostgreSQL. Also, I would need a way to convert it back from signed integer to unsigned hex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hex string to signed int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727875/hex-string-to-signed-int-in-python)

Comment: No, that performs a two's complement. This question is asking how to interpret an unsigned integer as a signed integer via the difference (i.e. the 9223372036854775807)

Comment: No, your question *as asked* is about interpreting an unsigned hex string as a signed integer.

Comment: I see, feel free to edit the question title, but hopefully the description makes sense. Still, are there any other options? I can also repost the question title.